# How to Zoom a Video in Qt (QVideowidget)?

Tags: qt, qt5

I have integrated **Qt5.0.1** with Visual Studio 2010.

I am using `QVideoWidget` to display my video. All works fine, i need to zoom my video.

I try to resize the `QVideoWidget` by doing `QVideoWidget::resize(width,height)` but the video is not resizing.

Comment: Do you have code?  In some cases the resizing of a widget is determined by a layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to place a [video item](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qgraphicsvideoitem.html) into a [graphics scene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html).  This will allow you to resize the video and essentially "zoom" in.  You can google for tons of [tutorials on how to manipulate items](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b35JF4LqtBs) in the scene - they should all work in a similar fashion to other 2d items.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
  player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("video.mp4"));

  videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem();
  player->setVideoOutput(videoItem);
  ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene());
  ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(videoItem);
}
```

Comment: ya actually i try the above code my video is playing, but in screen it cannot render properly. but playing through with Qvideowidget only plays fine.

Comment: what does "cannot render properly" mean?  can you update your post and provide code?